# WebView Taking Long time to load

Tags: android, url, webview

I am integrating Skrill payment gateway with my android app.As there is no available sdk so I have to redirect my app to skrill homepage.I am using a webview.But the problem is the webview is not showing the webpage and it shows blank screen.I cant figure out the problem.Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView wbskrill;
String url;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wbskrill=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wbv);
        url="https://www.skrill.com/en/";

        wbskrill.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
       }
        //wbskrill.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



     public void open(View view){
        wbskrill.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        wbskrill.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wbskrill.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wbskrill.loadUrl(url);

       }

     private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
          }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case overide methods of webview use to handle SSL certificate and accept ssl certificate it will run successfully.

```
public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {


 handler.proceed() ;


 }
```

**In your case**

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
          }

@Override 
public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

     handler.proceed() ;

     }
       }
```

For more info see this link [Android WebView with https loadUrl shows blank/empty page](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/)